# Writing data to Cassandra table from Kafka topic failing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have written simple job which consumes the data from Kafka topic and writes it to cassandra table . I can see data being printed to Console however when it comes to writing it to Cassandra job fails with -

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.JavaConverters$.mapAsScalaMapConverter
```

I am using Kafka 3.2.1 , Cassandra 3.11.13 ,pyspark 3.3.0.

my spark-submit command -

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:3.3.0,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.2.1 --jars /home/hdoop/jars/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar iwd_dproc_new.py
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly note on how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using connectors compiled for different Scala versions:

- Kafka connector is compiled with Scala 2.13
- Cassandra connector is compiled with Scala 2.12

It's not clear what version of Scala is used for Spark, but you need to take version that uses Scala 2.12, because there is no Spark Cassandra Connector for Scala 2.13.  And adjust Kafka connector version as well

Comment: Hi Alex  ,I have changed as per your suggestion - my new command is "spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.2.0 iwd_dproc_new.py" . However I am still getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaTokenUtil$.needTokenUpdate" error . [Kafka version -kafka_2.12-3.2.0 | Casanda version - 4.0.6 | Spark - 3.3.0 (Using Scala version 2.12.15)]. Not sure whats going wrong here .

Comment: Hi, It was my mistake , your suggestions worked.Thanks . Its like all jars should have matching versions With Spark which was 3.2.0 in my case .